# React Native Firebase doesn't work until removing app and reinstalling it

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase realtime DB in my React Native project. It works normally, but sometimes it stops without any error and cannot make it work without uninstalling app from device and then reinstalling it.

Comment: This cannot be resolved unless you know the error. Find errors by debugging.

Comment: You must debugging your project also maybe you can add a basic error handler log system.

Comment: Problem is: there is no error. It seems that android sometimes prevents internet connection